# Let $x = 2441921$. Factor $x$ into a product of primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $x = 2441921$. Factor $x$ into a product of primes.

I found that:
$1519^2 −x=−134560= −2^5 ·5 · 29^2$ and
$1541^2 −x=−67240= −2^3 · 5 · 41^2$.

I am trying to figure out what to do from here. How to find the product of primes with what I have found.

If I find a square closest to x being 1563^2=2442969. What should I do from here?

Comment: Since $x$ is odd, $15192-x$ and $15412-x$ are also odd, so that can't be true

Comment: Well I know those aren't the prime numbers. I already know the answer is supposed to be 811 x 3011. I just don't know how to get there from here.

Comment: What methods are you familiar with? An hour of trial divisions would get you the result, but it really doesn't look like you're doing that. Are you trying Fermat factorization?

Comment: @dgrasines517, the OP meant $1519^2$ and $1541^2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes thank you for noticing! I hadn't even noticed I will fix that.

Comment: I just found the square closest to x and got 1563^2 = 2442969

Comment: What should I do from here? In earlier questions that I had like this I just used trial and error from here finding primes closest to that number that multiplied to get x. But is there another way to do it? @T.Bongers

Comment: I'm curious, by what process did you find the numbers $1519$ and $1541$?

Answer (score 5):

You can write what you found as

$$1519^2\equiv -2^5\cdot5\cdot29^2\mod x$$
and
$$1541^2\equiv-2^3\cdot5\cdot41^2\mod x$$

This implies

$$1541^2\cdot2^2\cdot29^2\equiv 1519^2\cdot41^2\mod x$$

which is to say that $x$ divides

$$(1541\cdot58+1519\cdot41)(1541\cdot58-1519\cdot41)=151657\cdot27099$$

which is to say, the *factors* of $x$ must be among the factors of these two numbers.  Can you go from here?

(Note:  one can systematically compute $\gcd(x,151657)$ and $\gcd(x,27099)$.)

Comment: Yes, I can do this using Euclid's algorithm. Thank you!

Comment: @RayC.C., actually, if you think things through more carefully, you can get the non-congruence *equation* $151657\cdot27099=(58^2-41^2)x=99\cdot17x$....